# Build Pipeline Architecture of Vercel/Netlify?

Tags: build, containers, netlify, vercel

I use Vercel/Netlify on a daily basis. However, there is still little information available on how the build process looks behind the scenes. Are they using Docker to provision a build environment? What does the architecture look like?

It would be great if someone could explain this to me!

Comment: Please be more specific when asking questions.  Be sure not to ask too general questions.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: I believe their goal is to liberate you from thinking about such things. Side-note: I've noticed vercel changes their build process over time (based on the build log), it seems way more efficient now.